# Jmeter-Automation using Spring and Maven - Random Number Generation using javascript Issues

Tags: javascript, java, spring, maven, jmeter

I have already existing **jmeter** scripts(which I cant change) which generates a random number using javaScript to generate Url parameters dynamically. Problem is the javascript itself is printed in the url as parameter instead of the number it shoud generate. (All of this happens when using **Spring** and **maven** combo(WebService- JAX-RS))

I need it to be a web Project to simplify the execution of the regression scripts. The script is correct as It runs properly when using the Jmeter UI

Interestingly when I run it using a main method It runs and generates the random number using **JavaScript**. I have all the jars under a standard download of Jmeter Installation in the classpath. I need help in either getting all files in classpath to the maven build or the dependencies of all to be added to get it working.

The Javascript is as follows :

```
72AE-442A-93C5-SWID1${
__javaScript(vard=newDate();varday=d.getDate();if(day<10){
    day='0'+day;
}varmonth=d.getMonth()+1;if(month<10){
    month='0'+month;
}varyear=d.getFullYear();varhour=d.getHours();if(hour<10){
    hour='0'+hour;
}varmin=d.getMinutes();if(min<10){
    min='0'+min;
}varsec=d.getSeconds();if(sec<10){
    sec='0'+sec;
}varmsec=d.getMilliseconds();if(msec<10){
    msec='00'+msec;
}elseif(msec<100&&msec>=10){
    msec='0'+msec;
}currentDate=min+''+sec+''+msec)
```

}

If more details are required Please tell me

https://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui

Using the Fourth way in the following link but calling the same logic via a Webservice 
Thanks